# Duplicates? Where should I put my question?

Tags: support, migration, exact-duplicates

I asked a question about Neural Networks in the Signal Processing site
[Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40887/neural-networks-for-rotated-character-or-shape-recognition)

However now, checking the different sites I wonder if this is more on topic in Cross Validated?

And second, What is the proper procedure here? Post the duplicate or move the question?

Comment: On the second thing, see the advice in the [help/on-topic] on crossposting (3rd last paragraph) and [this meta post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/crossposting-on-the-stackexchange-network) - pick the best place and post it there. You can flag for migration if you need to shift it. There's a bit more flexibility if you seek different kinds of answers (e.g. "should I run this drainage pipe along a fence-line" might get very different kinds of answers if you post to diy.SE than on law.SE --- there's some scope for tolerance of crossposting in that case)